# Executing a powershell command with psexex and runAs

Tags: windows, powershell, psexec

I have to execute a powershell command to create a new cluster with PSExec. The command is invoked from Command Prompt (administrator)

PSExec is used to create a new session with domain user.

`C:\sysinst.tf\installs\psexec64\PsExec64.exe -s -u vini -p "domain_admin_password" -accepteula cmd /c "powershell -Command 'New-Cluster -Name clusterName -Node WindowsNode01-name2.ad_domain_stage,WindowsNode01-name1.ad_domain_stage -StaticAddress cluster_ip_address -AdministrativeAccessPoint ActiveDirectoryAndDns' -Verb RunAs"`

This is the command that I am trying to execute, but it says that the `-Verb Runas` is not a valid parameter.

How should I place the -verb runAs so as to execute the command in an elevated powershell

Comment: `-Verb runas` would only be used with `Start-Process`. (I don't think that would work remotely anyway, since the UAC prompt wouldn't be visible remotely and would wait for input, thus hanging your command indefinitely.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Is there any way i could get it running remotely? I tried the Start-Process as well but still it doesnt help. Only my cmd is being opened as Administrator and the powershell doesnt look like it is opened as Administrator

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com).